# QPixmap.loadFromData() does not load image from QByteArray

Tags: qt, arrays, qpixmap, qdatastream

I'm creating a socket-based program to send a screenshot from one user to another user. I need to convert a screenshot to a byte array before sending. After I convert my screenshot to a `QByteArray` I insert 4 bytes  to the beginning of the array to mark that it is a picture (it is the number 20 to tell me it is a picture and not text or something else).

After I send the byte array via a socket to other user, when it is received I read the first 4 bytes to know what it is. Since it was a picture I then convert it from a `QByteArray` to `QPixmap` to show it on a label. I use `secondPixmap.loadFromData(byteArray,"JPEG")` to load it but it not load any picture.

This is a sample of my code:

```
 void MainWindow::shootScreen()
 {
     originalPixmap = QPixmap(); // clear image for low memory situations
                             // on embedded devices.
     originalPixmap = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->grabWindow(0);
     scaledPixmap = originalPixmap.scaled(500, 500);

     QByteArray bArray;
     QBuffer buffer(&bArray);
     buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
     originalPixmap.save(&buffer,"JPEG",5);

     qDebug() << bArray.size() << "diz0";

     byteArray= QByteArray();

     QDataStream ds(&byteArray,QIODevice::ReadWrite);
     int32_t c = 20;
     ds << c;
     ds<<bArray;
 }

 void MainWindow::updateScreenshotLabel()
 {
     this->ui->label->setPixmap(secondPixmap.scaled(this->ui->label->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
 }

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    shootScreen();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    secondPixmap = QPixmap();
    QDataStream ds(&byteArray,QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    qint32 code;
    ds>>code;
    secondPixmap.loadFromData(byteArray,"JPEG");
    updateScreenshotLabel();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked` implementation looks odd.  You have...

```
QDataStream ds(&byteArray,QIODevice::ReadOnly);
```

which creates a read-only `QDataStream` that will read it's input data from `byteArray`.  But later you have...

```
secondPixmap.loadFromData(byteArray,"JPEG");
```

which attempts to read the `QPixmap` directly from the *same* `QByteArray` -- bypassing the `QDataStream` completely.

You can also make use of the `QPixmap` static members that read from/write to a `QDataStream`.  So I think you're looking for something like...

```
QDataStream ds(&byteArray,QIODevice::ReadOnly);
qint32 code;
ds >> code;
if (code == 20)
  ds >> secondPixmap;
```

And likewise for your `MainWindow::shootScreen` implementation.  You could reduce your code a fair bit by making use of [`QDataStream & operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const QPixmap &pixmap)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#operator-lt-lt).